# Derivatives in different systems of coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

I stumbled upon a problem while reading about the gradient operator in different coordinate systems.

If, for example, I am given a function $$f=x^2+y^2+z^2 + 2x$$
and I have to find $\nabla f$ in spherical coordinates I proceed like this (just for one direction
($\theta$) ):

1. Compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$
2. Because if I move $\theta$ a little ($d\theta$) in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ space of the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ coordinates, I move more ($rd\theta$) in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ space of the (x,y,z) coordinates , I have to divide $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ by $r$

My question is why do I have to come back to the $(x,y,z)$ space? Because if I define another function $$g(r,\theta,\phi)=f(x(r,\theta,\phi),y(r,\theta,\phi),z(r,\theta,\phi))$$
in the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ space, the "slope" (gradient) would be different.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question. If you are asked for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ then you shouldn't go back to $(x,y,z)$ coordinates. I don't understand what you mean by " why do I have to come back to the (x,y,z) space? "

Comment: Let's assume I have a scalar field over $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I have to compute the gradient in the spherical coordinate system. First, am I allowed to say that I have two "spaces" having 3 dimensions, the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ "space" where I consider $(r,\theta,\phi)$ to be like some "cartesian" coordinates and the $(x,y,z)$ "space"?

Comment: It's not 2 spaces. It's two ways of representing the same space.

Comment: I was trying to think like when making a change of variable in an integral. I have the (u,v) space and the "normal" space, where I initially started. That way, a "straight" line in the (u,v) space can be a "curved" line in the original space.

Comment: Yes that's true. It can happen that some function looks different in other ways of representation. I don't understand how that is related to the question though? If you want to differentiate by $\theta$, then use the chain rule as done in my answer. If you want to integrate, then indeed you have to multiply the term in the integral by $r^2\sin \theta$, to make up for the phenomenon you described. Does this answer your question? Am I in the ball park? :P

Comment: The problem was about the different slopes of f and g, the relation between them being described in my original post. So I have to find the slope "in the original space"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question...However, the way I would differentiate this is with the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}=(2x+2)r\cos\theta \sin\phi+2yr\cos \theta \sin \phi-2zr\sin \theta=(2r\cos \theta \sin \phi+2)r\cos\theta \sin\phi+2r\sin \theta \sin \phi r\cos \theta \sin \phi-2r\cos\theta \sin \theta$$

You can simplify it if you like.

Let's remind ourselves of the chain rule:

if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable in $n$ variables $(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ and each $x_i$ is differentiable in $m$ variables $(s_1,s_2,...s_m)$ (meaning $x_i: \mathbb R^m \to R$) then:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s_i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial s_i}=\nabla f \langle \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial s_i},\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial s_i},...,\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial s_i}\rangle$$